# How to replace all special characters in a string with space

Tags: javascript, xslt

I am trying to replace all the occurrences of @ in a string '217Z2800343645@@@@@@@25.00' with space using JavaScript regex expression

```
var addendaSpace = '217Z2800343645@@@@@@@25.00'

addendaSpace = addendaSpace.replace(/@/g,' ');
```

I am getting an output like this '217Z2800343645 25.00'

Comment: Are you putting this output into HTML? HTML will consolidate multiple spaces into seemingly one space when it renders.

Comment: Why is this tagged "xslt"?

Comment: JavaScript is used in xslt file to format the report data. output is a htm file

Answer (score 1):

Heres a snippet.  Dk if it's what you're looking for..

```js
var ad = '217Z2800343645@@@@@@@25.00'

var ada = ad.replace(/@/g, " ")

console.log(ada)
```

Answer (score 1):

html ignores mutlible spaces
either use `<pre></pre>` tag to preserve spaces 
or use nonbreakablespaces (`&nbsp;`)

https://jsfiddle.net/agfwo8hu/

```
<pre>hello   test</pre>
<p>hello &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test</p>
```

Comment: I am modifying the data in xslt file using javascript. Is there something i can modify in xslt file to dsiplay spaces